# How to delete object from Cosmos DB without knowing the partition key value?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

**If I don't have the partition key value, how do I delete a document?**

I have the `id` of the document and the property name of the partition key (in my case: `type`).

I tried:

```
var docLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, documentId);
var resp = client.DeleteDocumentAsync(docLink).Result;
```

Got error: `PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.`

Example document:

```
{
   "id": "AB12CD", 
   "type": "Company", 
   "Address": "123 Test Street"
}
```

---

**I tried to get the partition key value for the specific document id**

Using C# code...

I tried to read the document by its `id` and then pull the `type` value, but I got error: `InvalidOperationException: PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.` for using the following code.

```
var response = client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, id)).Result;
```

I also tried a Cross Partition Query by trying:

```
FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 10 };
queryOptions.EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true;
var queryString =  "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id= '" + id + "'";
var QueryInSql = client.CreateDocumentQuery<JObject>(
                documentCollectionUri,,
                queryOptions).AsDocumentQuery();
var result = QueryInSql.ExecuteNextAsync<JObject>().Result;

res = result.ToList<JObject>(); //if result has nothing, will be empty list
```

^ returns an empty list. If I check on the Azure Portal, I can see the document with that specific id does exist in the db.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just refer to this [doc](https://www.lytzen.name/2016/12/06/find-docs-with-no-partitionkey-in-azure.html), you will find the answer.

In C# code, please use `Undefined.Value` and everything will be fine.

```
client.DeleteDocumentAsync(
          UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DbName, CollectionName, id), 
          new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value) });
```

Hope it helps you.

---

***Update Answer:***

Maybe I misunderstanding your requirement yesterday, let me make a new clarification here.

Firstly, you collection is partitioned by partition field: `type`.

1.If you do not know the value of partition key and the document does have a partition field ,please use `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` property.

```
FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions
        {
            MaxItemCount = 10,
            EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
        };
 var id = '1';
 var queryString = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id= '" + id + "'";
 var QueryInSql = client.CreateDocumentQuery<JObject>(
                        uri,
                        queryString,
                        queryOptions).AsDocumentQuery();
 var result = QueryInSql.ExecuteNextAsync<JObject>().Result;

 var res = result.ToList<JObject>(); //if result has nothing, will be empty list


 Console.WriteLine("\nRead {0}", res[0]);
```

2.If you know the value of partition key and the document does have a partition field,please pass the partition key property in FeedOptions.

3.If you know the document does not have partition field in a partitioned collection,please use `Undefined.Value`.

Comment: Does this work if I have specified the partition key? 

I am running a Create and Delete cycle:
    
    `ResourceResponse<Document> resp = client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionUri, item, reqOptions, true).Result;`  
 The partitionKey is `type`. I save the id value and then call: 
    `var docLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(dbName, collectionName, documentId);`

    `var resp = client.DeleteDocumentAsync(docLink,
          new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value) }).Result;`

Results in error: `Resource Not Found`

Comment: @erad Please see my update answer,any concern let me know.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In case somebody is coming here to `delete_item` using python sdk. If the item doesn't have a partition key defined

Pass empty dictionary to the `partition_key` param to delete the item.

```
cosmosContainerClient.delete_item(item['id'], partition_key={})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I am using a legacy collection with no PartitionKey and I couldn't figure out how to delete in these cases. Is there any documentation you found mentioning that? Because I looked around and couldn't find any mention to this.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` library you can delete a item using the following

```cs
await container.DeleteItemAsync<dynamic>(id, PartitionKey.None);
```