# Partition key error on deleting data from cosmos

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

**Update**

I am trying to move data from cosmos using c# .The code is reading all data from cosmos (approx 70k). I am looking to copy to blob and delete from cosmos.
But I am getting  error:

**Error** :`Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system.`
but I can see it is there as I am using same Document after reading as shown in code.

I also checked
[How to delete object from Cosmos DB without knowing the partition key value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904734/how-to-delete-object-from-cosmos-db-without-knowing-the-partition-key-value)

Though I can see in cosmos that I have a partion key "/content.provider.id" .
How can I use this partition key to delete .

```
            foreach (Document document in item)


            {
                var content = document.ToString();
                var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
                string blobId = String.Concat(document.Id);
                using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json.ToString().ToCharArray())))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await (ConnectionFactory.GetConnectionBlob(DestinationStorageContainerName, storageConnectionString)).GetBlobClient(blobId).UploadAsync(ms, true);
                        

                        await (ConnectionFactory.GetConnectionDocumentClient(cosmosAccount, cosmosKey)).DeleteDocumentAsync(
         UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(SourceCosmosDatabaseName, SourceCosmosCollectionName, document.Id),
         new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value) });



                        Console.WriteLine("All files copied to Storage - " + count);
                        count++;
                    }
                    catch (CosmosException ce)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ce.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine("data Coped" + count);
                    }


                }
            }
```

Comment: Why are you setting your partition key's value to `Undefined.Value` instead of the value of the partition key? When you created your documents, you had to specify a value for the property representing the partition key (in your case, `/content.provider.id`). Whatever that value is, you have to provide.

Comment: Hi,I could not find any document to pass hierarchical keys .Any suggestion how I can pass this in code? Unable to get dynamic value of provider.id for each document.I have 70k docs and does not seem logical to manually find value for each document.Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am looking to copy to blob and delete from cosmos.

**Below are the steps I followed to delete from Cosmos and store it in Blob:**

- Using the supplied Cosmos DB configuration, `CosmosClient` creates a Cosmos DB client.
- Uses the `ReadItemAsync` function to read a document from Cosmos DB.
- The document is identified by its **partition key** and **`cosmosDbItemIdToDelete`**.
- The value of the partition key is passed as an input to the `PartitionKey` constructor. I used the document's **Id** as the partition key value in the code.
- Use the partition key to identify the correct partition where the document resides. This ensures that the document is deleted from the correct partition.
- `cosmosDbItemIdToDelete` is used as the partition key value to locate and delete the document within the appropriate partition.
- The `BlobServiceClient` and `BlobContainerClient` for Blob Storage are created using the Azure Blob Storage SDK and the supplied configuration.
- The data from the Cosmos DB document is serialized into the necessary format and uploaded to Azure Blob Storage with the given `blobFileName`.
- Documents copied from Cosmos DB to Blob Storage are deleted using the `DeleteItemAsync()` method.

**Below Is the code I tried with:**

```cs
static async Task Main()
{
    string cosmosDbEndpoint = "*****";
    string cosmosDbKey = "*****";
    string cosmosDbDatabaseName = "newDb";
    string cosmosDbContainerName = "newCont";
    string cosmosDbItemIdToDelete = "1";

    string blobStorageConnectionString = "*****";
    string blobContainerName = "balaji";
    string blobFileName = "balajiDoc.txt";
    
    Console.WriteLine("Starting the data transfer and deletion process...");

    try
    {
        using CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(cosmosDbEndpoint, cosmosDbKey);
        Database cosmosDatabase = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(cosmosDbDatabaseName);
        Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Container cosmosContainer = cosmosDatabase.GetContainer(cosmosDbContainerName);

        ItemResponse<MyDocument> cosmosResponse = await cosmosContainer.ReadItemAsync<MyDocument>(
            cosmosDbItemIdToDelete,
            new PartitionKey(cosmosDbItemIdToDelete));

        Console.WriteLine("Document read from Cosmos DB.");

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobStorageConnectionString);
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerName);
        BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobFileName);

        using Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cosmosResponse.Resource)));
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true);

        Console.WriteLine("Document data copied to Azure Blob Storage.");

        await cosmosContainer.DeleteItemAsync<MyDocument>(
            cosmosDbItemIdToDelete,
            new PartitionKey(cosmosDbItemIdToDelete));

        Console.WriteLine("Document deleted from Cosmos DB.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

In Console:

```
Starting the data transfer and deletion process...
Document read from Cosmos DB.
Document data copied to Azure Blob Storage.
Document deleted from Cosmos DB.
```

In Blob:

```
{"Id":"1","Name":"Pavan","Age":25}
```

Comment: does it require MyDocument  class to be created from json ?

Comment: Also,what if conatiner dont have partition key . .Undefined.value will not work .Any suggestion .I am working with DocumentClient and not Cosmos Client but let me try same

Comment: The **MyDocument** class is used to both deserialize the document's JSON representation, which was obtained from Cosmos DB, and to serialize the document's data into JSON, which was then stored in Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: ok,I Desrialize without the use of additional class.But many thanks for input.I am using cosmos client so this solution does not work for me but I tried and it worked on seerate project. Accepting you answer